# Sorting 2d lists Alphabetically

Tags: python

i have a really long 2d list with strings of characters in the following form

```
[[Month, Item, Price],[Month, Item, Price],.......]]
```

the fake short version 2d list i have alphabetized  is

```
msl =[['March', 'cook', '4.53'], ['March', 'book', '3.23'], ['June', 'clothes', '1.52'], ['December', 'clothes', '3.42']]
```

What i am trying to do is write code without dictionaries or lambda to sort the items in alphabetical order by item. For example instead of `[['March','cook','4.53'],['March','book','3.23']` it becomes `[['March','book','3.23'],['March','cook','4.53']...]]` but the code i wrote does not seem to work and im not sure why. I wrote the following

```
if msl[h][0] == msl[h+1][0] : # If month is the same as next month
    print "true"
    size = len( msl )         # start an item dictionary sort(msl[i][1])
    unsorted = True
    while unsorted :
        unsorted = False
        i = 0
        while i < size-1 :
            if msl[i][1] > d[i+1][1] : #if the item is greater than the next
                print "true again"
                temp = d[i]            # temp = current sublist
                d[i] = d[i+1]          # current sublist becomes next sublist
                d[i+1] = temp          # next sublist becomes current sublist
                unsorted = True
                i = i + 1

else :
    h= h+1
```

i write the "trues" in there to check where the process of the program and it prints true to all of them but when i try to print out the new msl nothing comes out. Is it possible to write something like `while month remains the same, sort items` using the .sort method applying it to the item index but rearanging the whole sublist?

Comment: I can think of a way using lambdas. Any particular reason you don't want to use one?

Comment: It really boils down to `sorted(msl, key=operator.itemgetter(1))` (notice that you need to import `operator`). I wonder if your restriction of not using lambdas also applies to `operator.itemgetter`. Notice that, as presented, it will return a **new** sorted list. If you want to sort the list *in place*, then you simply write `msl.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))`.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a list of lists, and not a list of objects?  The former tends to be a bit brittle as requirements change.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make much sense of the code, because the `d[...]` referenced all over the place isn't defined anywhere in what you've shown.

In any case, you appear to be writing a bubble sort, which is a Very Bad Idea for "a really long list" - it's one of the least efficient sorting methods known.  Using the builtin `sort()` with a `lambda` or `itemgetter` (as @Arrieta suggested) is the best that can be done.

But it's never *required* to use a `key=` argument to `sort()`.  It's just sane ;-)  The older (and more wasteful) DSU (decorate, sort, undecorate) pattern can always be used instead:

```
>>> decorated = [(x[1], x) for x in msl]
>>> decorated.sort()
>>> msl[:] = [x[1] for x in decorated]
>>> msl
[['March', 'book', '3.23'], ['December', 'clothes', '3.42'],
 ['June', 'clothes', '1.52'], ['March', 'cook', '4.53']]
```

This works by "decorating" your original list by building a new list of 2-tuples, where the first element of each tuple is the sort key and the second element the original list's item.  Then a plain sort.  Then tear off the decoration.  The final `msl[:]` also replaces the original list's entire content with the sorted list.

The sequence:

```
>>> msl = [(x[1], x) for x in msl]
>>> msl.sort()
>>> msl = [x[1] for x in msl]
```

is another way to do it, but by creating a new list object (the list object `msl` is bound to changes - it does not change using the `msl[:] = ...` spelling).